# ANTLR ambigous reference - how to get output?

Tags: antlr, semantics, rules, ambiguity

So I have a rule for `statement` which can lead to more statements:

```
statement returns[String txt]
    :   '{'{
            $txt="{";
        }
        (statement{
            $txt+=$statement.txt;
        })*
        '}'{
            $txt+="}";
        }
    | ... //more rules // ...
    ;
```

I am getting

*reference $statement is ambiguous; rule statement is enclosing rule and referenced in the production (assuming enclosing rule)*

but don't know how to resolve it. Somehow I would need to tell ANTLR that I need the return txt of `statement` inside parent `statement`. Please help me out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `$statement`, ANTLR doesn't know if you mean the rule itself, or the `statement` inside `( ... )*`.

Try something like this:

```
statement returns[String txt]
    :   '{'{
            $txt="{";
        }
        (s=statement{
            $txt+=$s.txt;
        })*
        '}'{
            $txt+="}";
        }
    | ...
        ;
```

Comment: Bart, I already told you you're the best, but I'm telling it once more! Cheers :)

Comment: I'm by no means the best, but thank you anyway :) And you're welcome, of course.